# bootstrap datetimepicker need to add keyBinds conditionally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need to add the `keyBinds` for delete and enter button properties conditionally.
I tried using the `Object.assign()` method, but not sure how to get hold of datetimepicker object associated with my input control, and how do I enable or disable `keyBinds` conditionally.

```js
var $inputCtrl = $('.inputCtrl');
$inputCtrl.datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en-US',
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    useCurrent: false,
    keepInvalid: true
});

Object.assign($inputCtrl.data("DateTimePicker"), bConditionalDeleteTest && {keyBinds: {'delete': null}});
```

if we initialize this object statically, it would be

```js
$('.inputCtrl').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en-US',
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    useCurrent: false,
    keepInvalid: true,
    keyBinds: {'delete': null} /*this would disable the default Delete key behavior of the control.*/
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`keyBinds`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#keybinds) function.

> `keyBinds()`
>
> Returns a `string` variable with the currently set options.keyBinds option.
>
> `keyBinds(object)`
>
> Takes an `object` value.
>
> Allows for several keyBinding functions to be specified for ease of access or accessibility. See the options page for defaults.

You can have something like:

```
var $inputCtrl = $('.inputCtrl');
$inputCtrl.datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en-US',
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    useCurrent: false,
    keepInvalid: true
});

if( bConditionalDeleteTest ){
  $inputCtrl.data("DateTimePicker").keyBinds({'delete': null});
}
```